# Why is typescript complaining about filter and how can I resolve this?

Tags: typescript

I need your help with this typescript complaint, I have been struggling with this issue for quite a while now. I am trying to filter an array dynamically, but Typescript is complaining. Here is what it said,

```
(property) Array<T>.filter: {
    <S extends {
        x: number;
    }>(predicate: (value: {
        x: number;
    }, index: number, array: {
        x: number;
    }[]) => value is S, thisArg?: any): S[];
    (predicate: (value: {
        x: number;
    }, index: number, array: {
        x: number;
    }[]) => unknown, thisArg?: any): {
        x: number;
    }[];
} | {
    ...;
} | {
    ...;
}
```

Here is what I am trying to do:

```typescript
const shapes ={
  rectangles :[
    {x :1}
  ],
  ellipses :[
    {y :10}
  ],
  polygons :[
    {isFinished :true}
  ]
}

Object.keys(shapes).forEach(shapeKey => {
  shapes[shapeKey as keyof typeof shapes].filter(shape => {
  // 
  // 
  })
})
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBAWBDADgUwjAvAbwFAxgCdVgpEwBzAG3RgC4BtfAmbAD3oEYBfZgXQA0zVFSoBLZBFqNmBbAE8uABl4FBzZCCryK4DDJasxEAGJiwx+KgAm9KIQCuqVTD65euAPIAjAFYkoADoAa1R5CAAKBBR0AEpAgDMQQgBRRGB4KKQ0AGkwrAA+VmZotAgGUtQ8xUQMUPkQBJgoeTRGuGz0PkSxKihUQiyYwuKCAHoxmGYJqYJuWPcF3CA)

I am definitely using filter on an array. It should not be complaining. Please, if you know how to fix this, help me

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Comment: *( I've broken my rule about not editing code into questions for people because arguably the playground link already contained the code, just in an ... obfuscated form. :-) )*

Comment: *"Here is what it said."* You've left out the part where it tells you what the error is: *"This expression is not callable. Each member of the union type ... has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.(2349)"*

Comment: Any idea how to fix?

Comment: The usual solutions for dealing with unions apply: add code to determine which part of the union you're dealing with, and add guards so TypeScript knows that. It's hard to give you a specific answer when you haven't said what you want to do.

Comment: I see, I will look up and try to find the solution. It's  quite simple what I am trying to do. I just want to filter an array.  Here is a full code that includes what I am trying to do. If you could help me, I would really appreciate it. Thanks anyway❤️❤️.

Comment: Just FYI, what you're trying to do *isn't* all that simple from a type perspective, because the arrays have nothing in common with each other. That's why you need to differentiate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the three different kinds of arrays have nothing in common, so there's no overload of `filter` that matches the union of the three types of arrays.

You could go the pure type safety route and have some type predicates:

```typescript
type Rectangle = {
    x: number;
};
type Ellipse = {
    y: number;
};
type Polygon = {
    isFinished: boolean;
};

function isRectangleArray(shapeArray: any[]): shapeArray is Rectangle[] {
    return "x" in shapeArray[0];
}
function isEllipseArray(shapeArray: any[]): shapeArray is Ellipse[] {
    return "y" in shapeArray[0];
}
function isPolygonArray(shapeArray: any[]): shapeArray is Polygon[] {
    return "isFinished" in shapeArray[0];
}
```

That lets you differentiate between the arrays:

```typescript
Object.keys(shapes).forEach((shapeKey) => {
    const entry = shapes[shapeKey as keyof typeof shapes];
    if (entry.length > 0) {
        if (isRectangleArray(entry)) {
            const result = entry.filter((rect) => {
                // ...
            });
        } else if (isEllipseArray(entry)) {
            const result = entry.filter((ell) => {
                // ...
            });
        } else {
            const result = entry.filter((polygon) => {
                // ...
            });
        }
    }
});
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-1NkAjsdMB3ZDDT2frq9QJcrtdf2ITdtw3PcDznHcbygO9+yCc8X2AcdlhqVkdC-L0gOIf9Vx1H9yxA-D2CqYjCKAA)

The code for each loop is completely different, because they're dealing with different things.

Alternatively, you could trick TypeScript into thinking that instead of a union of array types (`Rectangle[] | Ellipse[] | Polygon[]`), you have an array of union types (`(Rectangle | Ellipse | Polygon)[]`):

```typescript
Object.keys(shapes).forEach((shapeKey) => {
    const entry = shapes[shapeKey as keyof typeof shapes] as (Rectangle | Ellipse | Polygon)[];
    // −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    const result = entry.filter((whatever) => {
        // ...
    });
});
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDGwCGA7A5gG2gXigbwCgpioAPALihQFcBbAIwgCcBuAgXzdEigFEMMASzABnHPiIkQlGg2ZtOBbtAAKAewwg0alFFyESUQSIBiglMYAWEACaV6ajRFQK2BeDpHAoIy0kgiehKGTAjI6FgilADaeGSUAIxQ7AC6ADSSxBACwmJRULFQ0lAJAAzJ6ZlQYBpanjFxxmYWvraUwEzU0KkZigQA8vQAVmEAdADWECAiABS+-hAiAJSjAGZqTLxI8JYzc36QANJTS3oAfMEkHiheUBAoHSBB8wHRLxDHT0iBkyBqq1BlP8fAdFikoN8oDM4IhUJhoAAfPg5USIqDqTTaFBLaIpNiGa63UIiagYby4e6PNaCMnMPahRCnbAXAyGEgAenZUFGPKq7CWCgFBCAA)

That's technically incorrect, what you have is a union of distinct array types, but it lets you write a single `filter` call.

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate it. This way solved my issue.